# Adding more verbose detail to DocuSign Connect and API logging

Tags: docusignapi

We are encountering inconsistent results with DocuSign Connect integration where some envelope transactions are received by the listening server while others are not. This DocuSign integration involves two web servers with load balancing (listening app on both). The existing log details lack enough troubleshooting data to describe reason for the Connect failure events.

Comment: didn't see a question, but if you want I can try to make some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign Connect logs the responses it receives from the customer's Connect servers (or "listeners"). But Connect is merely the client of your servers.

The best logging will be your servers' logs.

Are your servers processing the incoming notifications synchronously or putting the notifications messages onto a queue and then later processing the messages asynchronously? The latter is a more reliable and recommended pattern.

You may want to consider switching to a PaaS solution that incorporates asynchronous queuing:

If you use a PaaS (Platform as a Service) system such as AWS or Azure, the cost of the intermediate system will be zero (AWS) or very low (Azure, etc) for as many as a million messages per month.

In addition, the PaaS pattern will enable your application to receive the notification messages from behind your firewall, with no changes to the firewall.

More information: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-webhook-listeners-part-4/

Code examples for AWS, Azure, Google Cloud for C# .NET Core, Java, Node.js, PHP, and Python are available from DocuSign’s GitHub repository. See the repository listing via [this link](https://github.com/docusign?q=connect-%20in%3Aname&type=&language=). The repos all start with Connect-

After you receive a notification message, your application can use it to trigger a download/storage of the envelope’s documents; to start a new process since the envelope has now been signed, etc.